# How to turnoff machine completely in azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

In AWS, when I turnoff my windows machine with shutdown command inside it.
The AWS portal, it will show as turned off.

But in azure, if I turnoff from portal, it is releasing IP and showing as turned off.

[image: turnoff from portal]

But if I turn it off from machine, it is showing as stopped but not deallocated and keeping the public IP still.
[image: shutdown from machine]

[image: stopped only]

What is the billing difference in the above two?
And, users will ask us to turn it on when they use it and shutdown the machine from their end. They will ask us to turn it on and we can provide the IP address as a reply to them manually through teams/skype.

So, is there anyway to change to stopped/deallocated when I turn off the machine from shutdown command on the machine?

How to

Answer (score 1):

Shutting down a VM will not deallocate the underlying resources and charges still applies. Stopping a VM will deallocate the compute resources and compute charges will stop.

You can stop a VM using the Powershell **Stop-AzVM** command or the Azure CLI **az vm stop** command.

In the comments, Alain made a clarification:

> Beware: Powershell Stop-AzVM will both stop & deallocate the VM, but
> the Azure CLI az vm stop will only shut down the VM (but continue
> charging for all assigned hardware). It requires a follow-up command
> az vm deallocate to be equivalent.

Comment: But we need to do it from user's end, who don't have access to portal/CLI. They have only access to this machine. Configuring CLI on that machine is also not an option as it will give access to complete account

Comment: One option: Start/Stop VMs during off-hours https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management

Comment: Can we do anything from that VM? Because there are many machines like that and setting off-hours is also not feasible as it might turn off the machine.

Comment: Another option: Deallocate Azure VMs automatically using a RunBook https://azurecloudai.blog/2020/05/14/azure-deallocate-stopped-vms-automacatlly-and-save-yourself-money/

Comment: I will try this option and let you know. Also, I saw an api in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58480090/how-do-i-create-a-job-in-jenkins-to-start-and-stop-the-azure-vms   as the first answer. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/start But how to use this api, can we just create a shortcut to launch this API call linked to a machine, is there any token generation to do for this purpose?

Comment: The answer is in the doc you referred

Comment: Beware: Powershell `Stop-AzVM` will both stop & deallocate the VM, but the Azure CLI `az vm stop` will only shut down the VM (but continue charging for all assigned hardware). It requires a follow-up command `az vm deallocate` to be equivalent.

Comment: Thanks Alain. I edited the answer adding your comment.